# Firebase iOS is not opening my app from Safari

Tags: ios, hyperlink, safari, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I tested the dynamic links Firebase. Configured everything in the project, the implementation did exactly like the Google documentation and created links on the console. When I test in Safari it does not open the application.

Thank you

Comment: What does this question mean?

Comment: Can you add your dynamic link?

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 9+**

Due to the limitations on the iOS platform, Firebase Dynamic Links must rely on Apple's Universal Link system to open the app directly from a link when it is installed. One of the constraints placed on Universal Links is that the app-open behavior is only triggered from a user's click and not by a redirect or copy/paste into Safari.

We have found it very challenging to test Universal Links in the simulator and pretty much always use a real device for this type of thing. Basic steps: install app > SMS link to your test device > click link > observe app open.

**iOS 8 and prior**

iOS versions prior to 9 handle opening the app from a Dynamic Link through Safari, so if the app is not opening when you copy/paste the link into Safari then some setup is incomplete. Please review your Firebase project for information and confirm that your bundle IDs/custom schemes match on the project page, in your link, and in your app; be sure that the bundle ID is listed in *URL Types* in your Xcode project setup along with any custom scheme you wish to use.

**Other Info**

Here is a link to a prior answer that may be helpful as well.
[Firebase dynamic link not opening the app iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724415/firebase-dynamic-link-not-opening-the-app-ios/38234369#38234369)

Comment: When I open link through Google Chrome in IOS, it redirects to the app, in case if I try to open link in Safari (even if I open link through sms or notes) it doesn't;t redirect to the app. What can be wrong? How is possible to fix it?

Comment: Since Chrome is also a Google product, it's likely doing some magic that doesn't rely on Universal Links; however, the other apps would rely on Universal Links. I'd guess that Universal Links is not set up correctly. Please take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html and confirm that each of the requirements are met.