# Firebase dynamic link doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, dynamic, ionic2, deeplink

I am making some app and use firebase dynamic link.
When I tested dynamic link on my android phone, It works well.
And in my iOS, it also works, but the page does not change and any parameter does not pass.

When I input deeplink like below picture on safari, it works well.

Is there something else that I missed?
I set Associated Domains on xcode.

I am using iOS 10 and using ionic2(cordova)!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using SMS app.

Paste your deepLink and send it. So when you click on the link your app will be open.

This answer also applies to the question: [Firebase dynamic link not opening the app iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724415/firebase-dynamic-link-not-opening-the-app-ios)

[Testing dynamic link using SMS app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVEKU.png)

Comment: that's aewsome.