# Firebase's Dynamic Link on iOS only works opening the link using Chrome

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, dynamic-linking, ios-universal-links

I configured my iOS App to handle a Dynamic Link I created using Firebase. So if I copy the generated link and paste it in Chrome's address bar, it works correclty: I get redirected to a preview page for my app with a button. Tapping on the button will open the store if I don't have the app installed, or open the app if it's already installed. When pasting the link in Safari's address bar, I get reidirected to the same page, but when I tap on that button, I am always redirected to the store, even if the app is already installed, instead of launching the app. Any clue about why this happens?

Comment: This looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724415/firebase-dynamic-link-not-opening-the-app-ios. See also https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/857

Comment: I've red all the possible comments, I changed the teamID in firebase's console with apps' prefix but nothing worked for me. Safari keeps opening the store

Comment: I also validated my Apple App Site Association file using https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/, and everything is ok. I discovered that in order to make an universal link work, I have to long-press the link (for example if I received it from WhatsApp) and select "Open with <MyApp>" option, but I don't have that option, only open with Chrome etc.
So something is wrong but I don't have any clue about what should I double check again

Comment: Did you try adding ?d=1 onto the generated link yet? If there are errors shown there, start by correcting those.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what `?d=1`is for. But I tried to append it now to https://myapp.page.link/apple-app-site-association and nothing new happened, always the same result

Comment: You can add that to your dynamic link, load it in a browser, and get an analysis of the link and any errors in config. Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug

Comment: I added as you suggested ?d=1 to my link (sorry for misunderstanding)
and I got the flow chart from Firebase without any error. So, as far as I can see, everything should be ok

Comment: I also run Firebase's diagnostic tool in my code, this is the output: ---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ---- Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 2.3.2 System information: OS iOS, OS version 12.1.2, model iPhone Current date 2019-02-01 10:21:39 +0000 Device locale it-IT (raw it_IT), timezone Europe/Rome Specified custom URL scheme is myapurlscheme and Info.plist contains such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key. AppID Prefix: ***123, Team ID: ***456, AppId Prefix equal to Team ID: NO performDiagnostic completed successfully! No errors found.

Comment: Please check this [Firebase dynamic link not opening the app iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724415/firebase-dynamic-link-not-opening-the-app-ios/65698622#65698622)